# Exit status of commands before last command

Tags: linux, macos, process, exit-code

On OS X, Linux, and other systems, you can use `$?` to get the exit code of the last command.  Is there any way to exit codes of older commands?  Either by saying "give me the exit code of the `nth` previous command" or by saying "give me the exit code of the process with PID `p`"?

Comment: you can append the exit codes yourself to a file after issuing commands

Answer (score 3):

The exit code of a command is output only once, and if not processed further the only thing that saves that exit code is the shell. `bash` only saves the exit code for the last command.

In order to look up the exit code of older commands you need to save them to a variable, like so:

```
$ echo "This command will succeed"
$ exitcode=$?

...

$ echo $exitcode
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you point me to some documentation that verifies bash only saves the last exit code?

Comment: I can't find anything explicitly stating so, but exit statuses by nature are lost unless explicitly saved. In `man bash` under "Special Parameters" we find the definition for $? `Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline`. There is no mention of looking up old exit statuses in bash manual.